# Calling NLTK's concordance - how to get text before/after a word that was used?

Tags: python, nltk

I'm would like to find out what text comes after the instance that concordace returns. So for instance, if you look at an example they give in ['Searching Text' section](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/ch01.html), they get concordance of word 'monstrous'. How would you get words that come right after an instance of monstrous?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
import nltk
import nltk.book as book
text1 = book.text1
c = nltk.ConcordanceIndex(text1.tokens, key = lambda s: s.lower())
print([text1.tokens[offset+1] for offset in c.offsets('monstrous')])
```

yields

```
['size', 'bulk', 'clubs', 'cannibal', 'and', 'fable', 'Pictures', 'pictures', 'stories', 'cabinet', 'size']
```

---

I found this by looking up how the `concordance` method is defined.

This shows `text1.concordance` is defined in `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/text.py`:

```
In [107]: text1.concordance?
Type:       instancemethod
Base Class: <type 'instancemethod'>
String Form:    <bound method Text.concordance of <Text: Moby Dick by Herman Melville 1851>>
Namespace:  Interactive
File:       /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/text.py
```

In that file you'll find

```
def concordance(self, word, width=79, lines=25):
    ... 
        self._concordance_index = ConcordanceIndex(self.tokens,
                                                   key=lambda s:s.lower())
    ...            
    self._concordance_index.print_concordance(word, width, lines)
```

This shows how to instantiate `ConcordanceIndex` objects.

And in the same file you'll also find:

```
class ConcordanceIndex(object):
    def __init__(self, tokens, key=lambda x:x):
        ...
    def print_concordance(self, word, width=75, lines=25):
        ...
        offsets = self.offsets(word)
        ...
        right = ' '.join(self._tokens[i+1:i+context])
```

With some experimentation in the IPython interpreter, this shows `self.offsets('monstrous')` gives a list of numbers (offsets) where the word `monstrous` can be found. You can access the actual words with `self._tokens[offset]`, which is the same as `text1.tokens[offset]`.

So the next word after `monstrous` is given by `text1.tokens[offset+1]`.