# Using conditional variables with nltk's concordance module

Tags: python, conditional-statements, nltk

I've just started working with nltk and am having trouble getting the concordance module to work with conditional variables. I would like to return a concordance for any given word in a Latin text, but since the language is inflected, I want to be able to specify the stem, identify any word in the corpus that contains the stem, and return a concordance for that. The code I'm using is:

```
book1 = open('Book1.txt', 'rU').read()
token1 = nltk.word_tokenize(book1)
text1 = nltk.Text(token1)

word = raw_input("What stem do you want to search?\n > ")

text1.concordance([w for w in text1 if w.startswith(word)])
```

Which returns the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\start_nltk_horace.py", line 68, in <module>
    concordance()
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\start_nltk_horace.py", line 49, in concordance
    text1.concordance([w for w in text1 if w.startswith(word)])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\text.py", line 314, in concordance
    self._concordance_index.print_concordance(word, width, lines)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\text.py", line 177, in print_concordance
    offsets = self.offsets(word)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\text.py", line 156, in offsets
    word = self._key(word)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\text.py", line 312, in <lambda>
    key=lambda s:s.lower())
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Just specifying `text1.concordance(word)` returns what I'm looking for without any issues (providing I input the fully-declined word), but I would have to repeat the function six-ish times to get a concordance for all of the different declensions of a word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're trying to supply NLTK's `concordance()` function with a list of words, when it only accepts a string. Try the following instead:

```
my_concordances = []
my_inputs = [elem for elem in text1 if elem.startswith(word)]
for input in my_inputs:
    my_concordances.append(text1.concordance(input))
```

Then, `my_concordances` should end up as a list where each entry is a concordance for a different word that started with the raw input string. You can also consider pre-allocating the space for `my_concordances` depending on what specific data type gets returned by the `concordance()` function, since you can just check the length of `my_inputs`. That might improve speed if it's an issue.

Note that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898131/calling-nltks-concordance-how-to-get-text-before-after-a-word-that-was-used) might be of interest to you too. It goes into more detail on `concordance()`.