# Regex: get accented letters with spaces

Tags: python, json, regex, string

I'm trying to extract a keyword from a JSON string and get the context of the word. My string looks like:

**JSON**

```
{"1" : "Na casa de meu Pai há muitos aposentos; se não fosse assim, eu lhes teria dito. Vou preparar-lhes lugar."}
```

Currently, my Python code is:

**Python**

```
re.findall(regex, string)
```

I want to provide a word (e.g. *Pai*) and get the words before and after the keyword. My script will count all the occurrences of the keyword and make a list of contextual words.

My problem is: how do I get the accented letters with whitespaces, commas, dots, etc? What is the best approach: list the desired chars or exclude the unwanted? Something like:

```
([^\"]+)Pai([^\"$]+)
```

Comment: The best approach would be to use a `JSON` parser and string functions instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load your JSON data via `json.load()` or `json.loads()`, then use the [`nltk.ConcordanceIndex`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8898784/771848) that would help you to explore the words around a specific word in a text, example:

```
import nltk

text = 'Na casa de meu Pai há muitos aposentos; se não fosse assim, eu lhes teria dito. Vou preparar-lhes lugar.'
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text)

c = nltk.ConcordanceIndex(tokens, key=lambda s: s.lower())
result = []
for offset in c.offsets('Pai'):
    result += tokens[offset - 2: offset]
    result += tokens[offset + 1: offset + 3]

print(result)
```

Prints `['de', 'meu', 'há', 'muitos']`.